# When did Loki cast a spell on Odin?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

When Thor, Loki, and Odin were talking to each other in Norway in *Thor: Ragnarok*, Thor asked Loki to remove his spell from Odin, and Odin said that he already somehow broke his spell.

> **Thor:** Loki, lift your magic.
>
> **Odin:** Took me quite a while to break free from your spell.

When did Loki cast the spell on Odin, and why?

Answer (score 6):

### During *Thor: The Dark World*

We see the identity of an Asgardian soldier on the Dark World apparently looking for survivors being taken by Loki.

Later, *this same guard* (Loki) reports to Odin that they have found a body which Odin assumes to be that of Loki.

Apparently, it's at this point that Loki cast's his spell and replaces Odin. We don't see Odin again until the throne room scene at the end, by which time, it's clearly Loki masquerading as Odin.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: Obviously not, but seeing as how the answer could not be any better may I begin to rectify the situation by a +1?